# How to find roots of equation $f(x)=0 \pmod p $, where $p$ is prime number?

Tags: algorithm-design, finite-field

$f(x)$is any nth degree equation $n>0$, how to find roots of $f(x)$ over prime modulo.

Comment: Is there any difference between the quadratic equation mentioned in the title of your question and the equation of arbitrary degree $n$ in the text of the question? For quadratic polynomials and $p > 2$, the standard quadratic equation formula $$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ works, but the roots might be in the _extension_ field GF$(p^2)$. For the case $p = 2$, the standard quadratic formula cannot be used. Can you tell why?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: actually (assuming $p>2$), the standard quadratic equation, with the squareroot and the division evaluated modulo $p$ should work; no need to bring an extension field into play...

Comment: @poncho : ​ It's analogous to how "the roots might be in" $\mathbb{C}$ even if the coefficients are all in $\mathbb{R}$. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @poncho Errr no. In a finite field of characteristic $p > 2$, half the nonzero elements have square roots _in_ the field, while the square roots of the other half lie in the _extension_ field.  For example, $1$ has square roots $\pm 1 = \{1,2\}$ in GF$(3)$ while the other nonzero element $-1 = 2$ does not have square roots in GF$(3)$, they lie in GF$(3^2)$. This is analogous to what Ricky Demer has said above; the coefficients of $x^2+1$ are in GF$(3)$ but the roots are in GF$(3^2)$ just as $x^2+1$ can be regarded as a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb R$ but roots in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: How are F and f related. Is f in the title the sames a s f in the text? What have you tried and what is your problem? Please improve your question.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: if the squareroot does not exist (in the prime field), then I believe that the quadratic equation does not have a solution.

Comment: @poncho Nobody is denying the fact that if $b^2-4ac$ does not have a square root in GF$(p)$, then the quadratic equation has no solutions in GF$(p)$; the solutions lie in GF$(p^2)$. But the standard formula _does_ tell you what the roots are, whether in GF$(p)$ or in GF$(p^2)$, just as it does, for example, for the real polynomial $x^2+1$ whose roots are found as $$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} = \frac{-0 \pm \sqrt{0^2-4}}{2} = \frac{\pm 2\sqrt{-1}}{2} = \pm\sqrt{-1}.$$ In short, I don't understand the point you are trying to make, and why you think that anything I wrote above is incorrect.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I'm not understanding the point *you're* trying to make; the original equation was over the field $GF(p)$; if it were to have a solution if we modified the equation to be over $GF(p^2)$, I don't see how a solution to that modified equation would be relevant to the original question...

Comment: What research have you done? The problem of finding roots of polynomials in finite fields has been extensively studied, and in particular is covered in many standard textbooks.

Comment: @poncho  GF$(p)$ is a _subfield_ of GF$(p^2)$ and a polynomial whose coefficients are in GF$(p)$ can be regarded as a polynomial whose coefficients are in GF$(p^2)$ if we choose to do so. **No modification of any kind is needed; it is the same polynomial with same coefficients.** GF$(p^2)$ _also_ has characteristic $p$; the sum of $p$ copies of _any_ element of GF$(p^2)$ equals $0$ (just as the sum of $p$ copies of any element of GF$(p)$ equals $0$). So, when the OP asks for solutions to $f(x) = 0\bmod p$, specifying an $x \in$ GF$(p^2)$ such that $f(x) = 0$ _is_ a solution modulo $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r_0$ be the root of $f(x)$, so $r_0$ should be in $\{0,...,p-1\}$ and $f(r_0)=0 \pmod p $. If we cant find such $r_0$, our polynomial haven't root in $F_p$.

If $p$ be small we can easily find such $r_i$(root of $f^i(x)$) and compute $f^n(x)=\frac{f^{n-1}(x)}{x-r_{n-1}}$ where $f^0(x)=f(x)$, then repeat this recursively for $n$. Founded $r_i$'s are roots of $f(x)$.

Program such as MAGMA and sage enable to factor your polynomial with large degree in seconds.

Also this theorem can help you:

> **Theorem:** Let $F_q\in \mathcal{F_1}$ . There is a deterministic polynomial time algorithm
>   solving any polynomial equation over $F_q$ .

For more detail about $\mathcal{F_1}$ you can see [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwislui2sObKAhXBDQ8KHc4uCtsQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.umd.edu%2F~jkatz%2FTHESES%2Fsze.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFxt3UoKTwzF7EC-Bn8CJKZUbyuLg&sig2=o4-bO5Pe8ZjtKeI3kTmE0g).

Comment: What if $p=3$? What is the root of $x^2+1$ that is in the set $\{0,1,2\}$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, $x^2+1$ haven't root in $F_3$.  But in $F_5$, $(x-2)\cdot(x-3)=x^2+1$.

Comment: Yes, but the first paragraph of your answer  claims that when $p$ is small, there is a root of $f(x)$ in the set $\{0,1,2, \ldots, p-1$. Or did you mean to say that $p = 3$ is far too large a value of $p$ for your method to be applicable?

Comment: I agreed your answer. But how to solve the equation if degree of the polynomial greater than 2? any reference is available.

Comment: @venkat, This method is correct for all degree. I edited my answer.

Comment: If the prime number is more than 192-bit, this formula will be applicable?

Comment: @venkat, In this case we have Theorem(Lu,Zhang,Lin) that is applicable for big number (192,1024,2048,...bit numbers). you can see "Factoring RSA moduli with weak prime factors".